# App Inventor app works in emulator, but not on my actual phone

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've got an app inventor app built and working pretty well in the emulator.  When I put it on my phone none of the code runs.  The app doesn't crash, but the code behind the objects doesn't do anything.  I've got code which runs on screen load which doesn't fire, and my buttons don't do anything.

The drop downs show the menu item, but that's it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to get 'any' app-inventor apps (like the tutorial ones) built and deployed/working on your phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you connected the phone with the Block Editor Open? Can u see live preview of the app being developed?

You need to install a small application "AppInventorPhoneApp" to the phone in-order to accomplishing this... Usually this will be installed when you connect the phone first time with your BlocksEditor...

Just connect the phone to the Blocks Editor. Blocks editor will automatically install this application. Then you can see the preview in Phone.

Click Download apk from app inventor. Then Click, Package for Phone--->Download To Connected Phone.

I hope this solves your issue.

Check if unknown Sources and Development options are turned on in the Application settings.... For an application to run without these, you have to sign it. (I am not sure about this)..

Comment: I have, but the block editor didn't see my phone.  I've got the app inventor stuff installed correctly (I think).  I'll check to make sure that I've got all the drivers installed correctly and see if that helps get the AppInventorPhoneApp installed on the phone.

Comment: OK, that did the trick.  When I do the package for phone > download to connected phone it puts a usable version on the phone.  Since I've got you here already, what's the best way to distribute an app from App Inventor to people (I know that the app store isn't an option)?

Comment: For distributing the app first download the app to your computer. Sign the app using your Unique Key. Upload it to the market.

Comment: http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/userfaq.html. Check out the 6th FAQ. You cannot Publish your applications to the market yet... App Inventor is not yet ready for that.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/apptomarket/ This is an work around for publishing the AppInventor app to the Market